# Google Scripts Package as both Web App and Web Add-on (Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to package a Sheets Web Add-on in such a way that the doGet functionality of Web Apps are available to the end user of the web add-on? I'd like to create full-screen HTML dashboards that the users of our Sheets Web Add-on can leverage to visualize their data. Our Web Add-on works and allows the user to collect their data but there doesn't seem to be a way to create a HTMLService (other than the side action bar) on which we can display the data. Am I missing something or is this not possible at present?

Comment: You may check this [blog: *Advanced Development Process with Apps Script*](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/advanced-development-process-with-apps.html) for the tips and best practices for developing more complex Apps Script solutions. I don't think it's possible. You can just either [publish an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) or [build a Web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) through Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks for the blog. That information is very useful. I too don't think it's possible but I was hoping I overlooked something or that it was on a roadmap somewhere.